# Is there a way to listen for popovers hide being called?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

## Problem

Using Twitter's Bootstrap (version 2.1) I am creating popovers and it would be really useful to me if I could bind to the popover hide event in order to perform some secondary actions.

Calls to `popover('hide')` are littered throughout the code, I don't think it would be practical to try and replace calls to them to something I could monitor easily.

Is there a tidy way to bind to this event?

## What I have tried

In order functionality that Twitter has created it normally namespaces events, something like `popover:hide`, so whilst it wasn't documented I did try and access the following;

```
$(document).bind('popover:hide', function() {
  console.log('popover hidden');
});
```

But this didn't work (it was a long shot!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `hide` event:

```
$(document).on('hide.bs.popover', function() {
    console.log('popover hidden');
});
```

It’s in the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ (popover -> Events)

```
This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.
```

Comment: Thanks - I believe that is maybe a feature of newer versions, certainly it doesn't appear to be working for me.

Comment: @Toby so you need to go back and check the docs that is relevant for your version. I’m sure there is an event for it, you just need the right one.